# Deriving the classical electromagnetic point charge Lagrangian from the Abelian Yang-Mills Lagrangian density

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, classical-electrodynamics

> Can I derive the point charge Lagrangian 
>   $$ L = -\frac{mc^2}{\gamma} - \frac{1}{c} J_{\mu} A'^{\mu}\tag{1} $$
>   from the Abelian Yang-Mills Lagrangian 
>   $$L = \int d^3x [ - \frac{1}{16 \pi} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{c} J'_{\mu} A^{\mu}] ~~? \tag{2} $$

I recognized that one is the Lagrangian for a point charge and the other is the Lagrangian for the EM fields, and I know that each is derived independently using Lorentz invariance, unit analysis and static limits (see Jackson sections 12.1A-B, 12.7) but surely there must be a relationship between the two?

The Lagrangian for a point electric charge located at $\vec{r}$ is, according to Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics" equation 12.12, $L = -m c^2 \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} +  \frac{e}{c} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{A}' - e A'_0 = -\frac{mc^2}{\gamma} - \frac{1}{c} J_{\mu} A'^{\mu}$, where $J_{\mu} = e \delta(\vec{r}) \cdot u_{\mu}$ and $u_{\mu} = \gamma(c,\vec{v})$. In other words, this is the Lagrangian for an electron of mass $m$ and four-current $J_{\mu}$ interacting with external electromagnetic fields $A'_{\mu}$. The associated action is $S = \int L dt = \int \gamma L d \tau$.

The Lagrangian density for the electromagnetic field $A_{\mu}$, according to Jackson equation 12.85 is $\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{16 \pi} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{c} J'_{\mu} A_{\nu}$, where $J'_{\mu}$ is the current density associated with external field sources/charges. In other words, this is the Lagrangian describing the dynamics of the electromagnetic field $A_{\mu}$ interacting with external field sources described by $J'_{\mu}$. The associated action is $S = \int \mathcal{L} d^4 x = \int L dt = \int \gamma L d\tau$.

**My attempt:**

I need to convert Lagrangian (2) from describing the dynamical fields $A_{\mu}$ interacting with external charge distributions $J'_{\nu}$ to something which describes the dynamics of a charge distribution $J_{\mu}$ (which generates field $A_{\mu}$) interacting with external field $A'_{\nu}$ (which is generated by $J'_{\nu}$).

I integrate by parts the $-F_{\mu \nu}^2$ term in equation (2) to obtain $A_{\mu} (\partial_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu}) + \partial_{\mu}(A_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu})$. According to the Euler-Lagrange equation $\frac{c}{4\pi} \partial_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu}=J'^{\mu}$, i.e. the change in the curvature $\partial_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu}$ results from the presence of the external current-density $J'^{\mu}$, analogous to how an acceleration results from an external force.

I believe the $\partial_{\mu}(A_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu})$ term should yield something like the electric flux through the boundary of the space for field $A_{\mu}$, which is just the charge, allowing me to derive a $J_{\mu}$ term (not a $J'_{\nu}$ term). But expanding this term gives $\partial_{\mu}(A_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu}) = \partial_0(-A_i E^i) - \partial_j(-A_0 E^j) + \varepsilon^{kij} \partial_j (A_i B_k)$.

But I get stuck here, and cannot seem to derive either a $J_{\mu}$ term or a mass term like $-m c^2 / \gamma$. Does anyone have any pointers for me? I'd be much obliged.

Note:

I have read the following and my question is not a duplicate of either, as I know the two Lagrangians above are derived independently using Lorentz invariance, unit analysis, and known static limits: 
[Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34241/), [How is the electromagnetic Lagrangian derived?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166481/)

Comment: I'm not so sure about "surely there must be a relation". One is the Lagrangian of a point particle in a background electric field, the other the Lagrangian of *the field itself*. The dynamical variables are completely different. Without better justification, it is unclear to me why you would expect to be able to derive one from the other.

Comment: At the level of eqs. of motion, the question (v2) seems to essentially be asking if the Lorentz force can be derived from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thank you for your comment and edits. I am truly interested in the _Lagrangians themselves,_ not the equations of motion or the relationship between the equations of motion. I am also not interested in deriving the Lorentz force from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Thanks for your interest. As I point out in line 4 of my question statement, I know that the Lagrangians describe the dynamics of different objects. I am interested in how the two Lagrangians are related to one another, even in a schematic way. For lack a of a better term, I should be able to at least put them into context with one another and find a point of connection between the two since (1) describes a charge distribution interacting with background fields and (2) describes fields interacting with a charge distribution.

Comment: At the level of actions, for the opposite question (v2), see also physics.stackexchange.com/q/55291/2451